# Open .tiff, set projection, then re-save in Python with GDAL

Tags: python, coordinate-system, gdal, osgeo

I am trying to set the projections of a .tiff file from another file with GDAL in Python.  I successfully set the projections, but how do I re-save the .tiff afterwards?

Here is my code:

```
ds = gdal.Open('satellite_image.tif')
prj = ds.GetProjection()

roads = gdal.Open('road_lines.tiff')
roads.SetProjection(prj)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to open the second file in update mode, then dereference it to save and close it.

```
roads = gdal.Open('road_lines.tiff', gdal.GA_Update)
roads.SetProjection(prj)
del roads  # save, close
```

Another method to apply a projection to a GeoTIFF file is to use the [geotifcp](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/geotifcp.1.html) utility.